# text color QPlainTextEdit QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have class

```
class plainTextEditor: public QPlainTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
   void setTextColor(const QColor &c); // default function setTextColor(const QColor &c) from QTextEdit
   {
      QTextCharFormat fmt;
      fmt.setForeground(QBrush(c));
      this->mergeCurrentCharFormat(fmt);
   }
};
```

And:

```
plainTextEditor *mainText = new plainTextEditor(centralWidget);
```

And i use this code in start window constructor:

```
ui->mainText->setTextColor(Qt::red);
```

But if i delete all text and write again, text color return to black.
I tried fix:

```
connect(ui->mainText, &QPlainTextEdit::textChanged, [this](){
   ui->mainText->setTextColor(Qt::red);
};
```

But if i select all text and paste, text color black in part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is set the color of all text simply, you can use Qt StyleSheet!

The following example changes the background color to black and text color to red:

```
QPlainTextEdit *edit = new QPlainTextEdit(this);

//StyleSheet here
edit->setStyleSheet("QPlainTextEdit {background-color: black; color: red;}");

edit->appendPlainText("HELLO!");
```

**EDIT:** Without using StyleSheet:

```
QPlainTextEdit *edit = new QPlainTextEdit(this);

//Here we are using the HTML capabilities of Qt
//Converting the string using toHtmlEscaped to allow html special characters to be displayed
//Using blockSignals to not generate loop on text manipulation
//Using <pre> tag to allow multiple spaces

connect(edit, &QPlainTextEdit::textChanged, this, [=]{
    const QString plainText = edit->toPlainText().toHtmlEscaped();

    edit->blockSignals(true);
    edit->clear();
    edit->appendHtml("<p style=\"color:red;white-space:pre\">" + plainText + "</p>"
    edit->blockSignals(false);
});

edit->appendPlainText("HELLO!");
```

Comment: i cant use StyleSheet

Comment: i cant use 2 and more spaces with  `edit->appendHtml("<p style=\"color:red\">" + plainText + "</p>");`

Comment: @SKIP: It's a HTML characteristic, surround the text with `<pre>` as on my edit.